# post processing in spring boot webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a method in a restcontroller. I need to convert input request to String and send to another destination after method execution is totally completed, ideally I should not affect in method processing execution, method should execute without additional delay.
In non webflux application I can use afterCompletion in HandlerIntercepter. But due to use WebFlux I cannot use that.
How can I make additional processing after controller method execution ends, and response returned to caller?

Answer (score 1):

If the logic you want to call is specific to this one controller, you could use `doFinally`. It is executed after your Stream (Mono/Flux) terminates. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doFinally-java.util.function.Consumer-

Example:

```
public class Playground {

    ConverterService converterService;
    PostProcessor postProcessor;

    public Playground(ConverterService converterService, PostProcessor postProcessor) {
        this.converterService = converterService;
        this.postProcessor = postProcessor;
    }

    public Mono<String> endpoint(Integer input) {
        return Mono.just(input)
                .flatMap(integer -> converterService.convert(integer))
                .doFinally(signalType -> postProcess(input));
    }

    private void postProcess(Integer input) {
        this.postProcessor.process(input);
    }

}
```

First the `converterService` is called. After the stream is terminated, the `postProcessor` is called in any case.

Comment: thank you. I had test it. But this solution blocks controller's response. For example if I call Thread.sleep(5000) in postProcess method then it will affect in controllers response, service will response in +5 seconds in this way. Ideally I need non blocking solution.

Comment: Is it possible that you have both spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux added as dependencies? When you start your server, does it use Netty or Tomcat?

Comment: No, only spring-boot-starter-webflux. It uses Netty.

Comment: Also, I tried implementing WebFilter, and in doFinallly I get expected non blocking result. But in  WebFilter in doFinally I have no success with catching request